# Remove quotes from string that is imported from localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a front-end page where user can create textarea by pressing a button and then save the information in the localStorage. When the load button is pressed, the same number textareas appear and their content comes from the localStorage. The problem is that when I retrieve the info from the localStorage, the value has  "", which I want to remove.

I have tried replace(/"([^"]+(?="))"/g, '$1');

```
i = localStorage.getItem('AllNum');
// Allnum is the is where the generated textareas are placed
    function add() {
//i represents the number of textareas
        i++;
        $('#alltxt').append('<div class="textarea"><input></input><textarea id="txt' + i + '"></textarea></div>');
    }

    function save() {
        for (var a = 1; a <= document.getElementById("alltxt").childElementCount; a++) {
            localStorage.setItem("txt" + a, document.getElementById('txt' + a).value);
        }
        localStorage.setItem('AllNum', i);
    }

    function load() {
        if (document.getElementById("alltxt").childElementCount < localStorage.getItem('AllNum')) {
            for (var i = 1; i <= localStorage.getItem('AllNum'); i++) {
                $('#alltxt').append('<div class="textarea"><input></input><textarea id="txt' + i + '">"' + invert(i) + '"</textarea></div>');
            }
        }
    }

    function invert(i) {
        var a = localStorage.getItem('txt' + i);
        a = a.replace(/"([^"]+(?="))"/g, '$1');
        return a;
    }
```

https://codepen.io/abooo/pen/RvbOzV?editors=1010

To test the code generate some textareas, then enter some values in them and press +. After this reload the page. Finally click Load button. You can see that 123 changed into "123"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have `""` around the text you are putting in.

In your load function, change `"' + invert(i) + '"` to `' + invert(i) + '` (Remove the two `"`).